# Tag scores displayed on the Tags tab and the Tag Badge tracker do not match

Tags: support, bug, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

On my profile page **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4546874/farhan-anam)**, in the `Activity` tab, below the block where reputation is displayed, I have set up the C# badge tracker. It shows:

[image: 21 / 20 Answers; 15 / 100 Score]

As you can see, I have 21 / 20 answers and 15 / 100 score. But in the tags page, it shows:

[image: 42 Score]

So, which one is the correct one? Why is it even different? Or am I confusing the two things which are completely different from each other?

There are a few questions which ask about calculations of tag badge scores, etc. But I could not find one which shows that the tracker and the tag page have different scores. So I don't think this is a duplicate.

**UPDATE**

The solution of the problem is to select some other badge to track and then re-selecting the C# badge. I wonder why it doesn't update by itself.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy

Answer (score 1):

I expected to find the explanation under this answer to [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395) or perhaps at [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work) but I could not.

I think what you are seeing is the difference between tag badges only counting questions that were tagged `C#` when first asked, and the tags page showing questions currently tagged with `C#`.

My understanding is that tag badges work that way to prevent tag badge chasers from editing a tag into a question they asked or answered with a view to bumping up their count and "earn" that badge sooner.

I do note that what I described above does contradict [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114976/215590) to [If I retag a question, does it count towards my own tag score total?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114974/if-i-retag-a-question-does-it-count-towards-my-own-tag-score-total) so maybe what I *think* happens is not correct.

Comment: I think what you *think* happens is correct, I don't have any proof and I'm no tag badge expert, so you can take my opinion with a grain of salt. But both the question and answer are just about 4 years old, so maybe during that time the devs changed the rules and didn't tell anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself by selecting another badge to track, then re-selecting the `C#` badge. I wonder why it doesn't update by itself.

Comment: You should edit your question then, retag as bug and explain what happened. (this is clearly a bug.)